# Would Dara turn into a dryad if he stayed in Brokilon?

Tags: the-witcher

In the Witcher Netflix series, Dara and Ciri go into Brokilon forest and drink the magic waters (I don't know if this also happens in the books; haven't read them.) My understanding of Witcher lore is that the dryads of Brokilon can be created by transforming people who drink the waters and stay there for an extended time. But also, dryads are exclusively female.

So, if Dara had stayed in Brokilon and continued drinking the water, would he have been transformed into a dryad? If not, what *would* happen to him?

Comment: Possible explanation is that some naturalized dryads are transgender, and Dara would have become a female dryad, but I doubt this answer would have anyia textual support from the show, books, or any other official source.

Comment: Books have no Dara character, and overall the events in Brokilon differ significantly from the show. Do you need a show-specific answer, or are you also interested how it worked in the books?

Comment: Well no answer was given in the show, so I'm just curious if any other sources like the books hint at what would happen to a male in Brokilon. It's possible the idea is never touched upon (or maybe the books say, "Any male who drinks the waters dies immediately," but I haven't read them so I don't know).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing of this happens in the books and the Dara character is invented by the TV series.

Human women who drink the waters of Brokilon turn into dryads and lose memory of their previous life. The dryads are all female, if this is because the mutagens in the water only affect women or if gender is a cultural/social thing enforced by their matriarchy isn't really clear. However, as there are no male dryads, they need human males in order to reproduce.

In the books (*Sword of Destiny*), Ciri goes to Brokilon alone and at a younger age, around 10 years old. She ended up there by accident when she ran away from home to escape a betrothal. Her escorts who were with her and went to search for her as she ran off got attacked by dryads and only one man survived. He is then taken captive by the dryads and given the choice to stay with them for mating purposes - he isn't offered to drink the waters.

In the books, both Ciri and Geralt actually meet for the first time there in Brokilon. He doesn't even realize that she is the Child Surprise promised to him at first. They both drink the waters, but they have to effect on Ciri, which is explained partially by the destiny theme - it's her destiny to go with Geralt - and partially by her Elder Blood.

Geralt drinks the waters and then have various hallucinations and visions (similar to what Ciri is experiencing in the show), then through them eventually understands that Ciri is Calanthe's granddaughter. He isn't a human but a witcher, already altered by similar mutagens as those in the water - it is said in the books that witchers can't mutate further by drinking the water.

Summary/to answer the question:

- If Dara would have gone into Brokilon, he would likely have been either killed or taken captive. The dryads do however tolerate a selected few outsiders, like Geralt.
- There aren't really any examples of human or elf males drinking the waters in the books and the dryads wouldn't allow it either. We don't know if male humans of elves can turn into dryads.

Comment: I don't think Dara would've been killed. Dryads have a beef with human kingdoms bordering Brokilon, but in *Baptism of Fire* they are shown to allow scoia'tael guerillas passage and rest in their forest; so they might tolerate him, since he is an elf.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I think that situation is more like "the enemy of my enemy is my friend", they didn't do that because scoia'tael were (mostly) elves, but because they were giving said border kingdoms a hard time.